# Formula to capture timestamp on Google sheets is causing an issue

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula in google sheets which captures the timestamp when the adjacent cell is edited for the first time. See formula below

```
=if(D1,D1,if(A1<>"",NOW(),""))
```

The formula was working fine till around April 27th. What is happening is that the timestamp is recalculating every time the sheet is re-opened. Curiously, this recalculation is only affecting the latest 5 or so rows.
I do have an alternative script which achieves the same purpose, but i would like to see if i can spot the bug here. I am not sure if the bug has to do something with [how often formulas are recalculated in sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515#zippy=%2Cchoose-how-often-formulas-calculate).

Will appreciate any help, thanks

[EDIT] Adding my code alternative here - the function runs on an on edit trigger

```
// set the timestamp when a change is done on the status columns
function record_timestamp() 
{
  // get information
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Sheet name
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var active = ss.getActiveCell();
  var row = active.getRow();
  var name = sheet.getSheetName();
  var column = active.getColumn();
  var val = active.getValue();
  
  //Logger.log(row + ' = ' + column + ' , ' + name);
  
  // if marked done or NA
  if (
    (EDIT_TABS.indexOf(name) != -1) &&
    (row > STARTING_ROW) && 
    (columnToLetter(column) == COLUMN) // helper.gs
  )
  { 
    // put in current timestamp
    var now = new Date();
    var edit_range = sheet.getRange(row, column + 1);
    
    //Logger.log('edit = ' + edit_range.getA1Notation());
    
    // put in timestamp if blank
    if (edit_range.getValue() == "")
    {
      //Logger.log('setting value');
      edit_range.setValue(now);
    }  
  }
}
```

[EDIT 1]
Adding the other function which is called - this will convert the column number to an alphabet ex: 0 converts to A, and so on. Also adding the other variables used in the script.

```
// related to on edit timestamp record
var COLUMN = 'U';
var EDIT_TABS = ['Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Quarterly', 'Yearly'];
var STARTING_ROW = 1;

function columnToLetter(column)
{
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0)
  {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}
```

Comment: to get timestamp you need to use a script - thats the only way

Comment: `NOW()` will recalculate every time the sheet is changed. If you want to keep that timestamp, I'd suggest you to use your script instead.

Comment: i have a script to do this, with an onedit trigger - the only issue is that if a value is copy pasted (Ctrl + V onto the cell) OR if values are dragged down from the above cells, in that case the script does not get fired. this is the only issue with the script, which if solved will resolve my problem

Comment: `the only issue is that if a value is copy pasted (Ctrl + V onto the cell) OR if values are dragged down from the above cells, in that case the script does not get fired` Are you using an `onEdit` trigger? Actions like copying a cell or dragging down cells cause an `onEdit` trigger to run. Can you provide your code, so that this behavior can be reproduced?

Comment: Added my code to the problem description - the function runs on an on edit trigger - but as i said if there is a drag down or a copy paste, then the function does not get fired. Do i need to re-do something on the script ?

Comment: What makes you think the `onEdit` is not firing? Are you checking the `Executions`? Because copy/pasting or dragging down cells cause this to run. Please provide code related to `columnToLetter` so that this can be reproduced.

Comment: good point - i will check the script executions on a copy paste - have also added the other function and variables in the code in the EDIT 1 section - appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

As mentioned in comments, `NOW()` will recalculate every time the sheet is changed, so it's not a good way to get static timestamps.

#### Workaround:

Nevertheless, this can be done via script. In your current script, timestamps are not getting written to all your desired cells in case there are multiple cells selected, because of two reasons:

- **Not retrieving multiple active cells**:

When retrieving your `active` range, you are using [getActiveCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell), which returns just one cell, even if you have selected several cells. You should use [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactiverange) instead.

Therefore, you should replace this:

```
var active = ss.getActiveCell();
```

With this:

```
var active = ss.getActiveRange();
```

- **Not writing to multiple cells**:

When setting the range where the timestamp should be written to, you're using [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column), which returns a single cell. I'd suggest using [offset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer)) instead.

Therefore, you should replace this:

```
var edit_range = sheet.getRange(row, column + 1);
```

With this:

```
var edit_range = active.offset(0,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use formula `now()` as your timestamp, definitely it will auto refresh the time every time you open the Gsheet, there is one simple to time stamp without the need for formula or Apps script, the magic is:

```
Control + : 

Control + Shift + :
```

[image]

Comment: but the first part of the formula is if(D1,D1 - this should ensure that if the timestamp is put into the cell once, then it should not repeat it.

Comment: If you use formula `now()` for timestamp, let say you perform this action today, it will show today, however when you open it tomorrow, the the `now()` will become tomorrow. So it is not same as definition of timestamp, but rather than show what is the `date` of today. A `timestamp` function will mean even you open the file next month, it will still show the date you perform the action.